# How to search and print specific parts in a String?

Tags: c++, string, search, offset, std

I am mainly looking for a standard function from the C++ library that will help me searching inside a string for a character then print out the rest of the string starting from that found character. I have the following scenario:

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main()
{
     string myFilePath = "SampleFolder/SampleFile";

     // 1. Search inside the string for the '/' character.
     // 2. Then print everything after that character till the end of the string.
     // The Objective is: Print the file name. (i.e. SampleFile).

     return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Please if you can help me completing the code, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract a substring from the string starting from the last `/`, but to be most efficient (that is, to avoid making a needless copy of the data you want to print), you can use `string::rfind` as well as `ostream::write`:

```
string myFilePath = "SampleFolder/SampleFile";

size_t slashpos = myFilePath.rfind('/');

if (slashpos != string::npos) // make sure we found a '/'
    cout.write(myFilePath.data() + slashpos + 1, myFilePath.length() - slashpos);
else
    cout << myFilePath;
```

If you needed to extract the file name and use it later instead of just print it immediately, then [bert-jan's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8277603/726361) or [xavier's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8277606/726361) answers would be good.

Comment: Check for `npos` would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
size_t pos = myFilePath.rfind('/');
string fileName = myFilePath.substr(pos);
cout << fileName;
```

Comment: pos should probably be size_t

Comment: 90%. Ideally, it's `std::string::size_type` ;-)

Comment: Well, yes :) But isn't size_type defined as size_t in, like, every implementation of standard library? Obviously, just because it is defined, it can be changed to anything in future implementations... Sweet c++...

Answer (score 0):

```
 std::cout << std::string(myFilePath, myFilePath.rfind("/") + 1);
```

Comment: This is the first slash, not the last.

Comment: You must also check if the slash is found anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might use _splitpath() see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx form MSDN.

You can split paths into components with this STD RTL function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this line describing the objective of your question:

```
// The Objective is: Print the file name. (i.e. SampleFile).
```

You can use the std::filesystem to do it quite nicely:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

fs::path myFilePath("SampleFolder/SampleFile");
fs::path filename = myFilePath.filename();
```

If you only need the filename without the extension:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

myFilePath("SampleFolder/SampleFile");
fs::path filename = myFilePath.stem();
```